# Authenticating for PEAP during Arch Install

Tags: internet, ethernet, arch-linux, peap

I am trying to install Arch Linux but can't get internet to work. My uni uses PEAP and MSCHAPV2 for ethernet but I have trouble authenticating with netctl and wpa_supplicant. Mobile tethering doesn't work even after

```bsh
dhcpcd interface
```

successfully finishes. Pinging any site has 100% packet loss. Issue is very similar to the one posted here, which was also not resolved:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493818/how-to-connect-to-ethernet-while-installing-arch-linux?rq=1

This post didn't help either:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188783

After running wpa_supplicant:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18YiOtBDe3tJtK84nqhSEig23XowDIP1k/view?usp=drivesdk

Wpa supplicant config:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=0
network={
key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
eap=PEAP
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
identity="myIdentity"
password="mypass"
priority=2
}
```

journalctl -xe output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18yU-jcZcsxPrWNBLYqsTvQUjJja-P9FB/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please show your EAP configuration and `wpa_supplicant -d ...` logs (at least a photo of).

Comment: @user1686 Added.